# How to select anchor class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can i get the value Communications?

```
<li class="current">
    <a href ="" class="sf-with-ul">
        Communications<span class="sf-sub-indicator"></span>
    </a>
```

Comment: This question is not related to SharePoint specifically and would be better asked on a JQuery forum.

Comment: @Patrick: You have been repeatedly warned about asking off topic questions. If there's something you're not clear about regarding this please e-mail team@sharepointoverflow.com. Your account has been suspended for 48 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answers are correct, but I'll add to it a tad.

If you want a solution that works consistently and you only want that one item (as opposed to a parent object containing all of the matches), you really need to tie it to an ID.

For an example, if this was a nav menu it probably has an id attribute (somewhere above it). It doesn't matter if that id is called on the ul tag, or on some higher object like a div or table. You can then grab instances of sf-sub-indicator within that ID to ensure it's processed consistently. Using a blanket selector like you are means if someone adds a anchor tag with that class it'll get returned back since there's no scope on it.

The better approach is to use something like $("#divid li.sf-sub-indicator").text();

Comment: Thanks for the solution and i get what you mean.
i'm using a UL and it has no id.But will work something out

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sf-sub-indicator");
```

see http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 0):

From your excerpt, there is no way to guarantee that an expression will return the value "Communications". It depends on the rest of your page.

Based only on your 4 lines, you can do this:

$("a .sf-with-ul").text()